# Subfloor prep for tile in old house

Tags: tile, subfloor, tiling

Photos were too big to upload, here is a link:  https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1DTvfB7t1N6GmmzYFvEv53RH2NSWzB4H-

Goal: I want to tile the kitchen and breakfast nook w/ 12 x 12 ceramic (was already tiled with same size ceramic on top of several layers of old flooring when I moved in, but it was a poor install and bad tile). The last layer of flooring is vinyl tiles with a million staples in them. They are tricky to remove and otherwise sturdy, smooth, and well adhered. A few questions:

1. Can I hammer down these staples, then put 1/4 inch exterior grade (BCX) plywood on top of the vinyl, then Laticrete Stratamat (uncoupling membrane similar to ditra) system?
2. I started to pull up the vinyl in one section but stopped, seeing how challenging it was and that the staples did not come up with it. There is a little less than 1/8 difference between that area and the vinyl. Again, is adding the 1/4 inch plywood throughout + uncoupling mat sufficient to deal with it? Similarly, they never installed the vinyl in the area of the range and dishwasher, but there is some other type of linoleum. Similar transition height there.
3. Does the plywood need to be both glued and fastened with screws? When used to make a smooth surface for uncoupling membrane and not structural support, does the wood still need to be staggered and played with 1/8 inch gap between pieces? I have a handy person "helping" and noticed he started putting wood down and did not stagger and space. Fyi I have 4x4 pieces instead of 4x8, had to cut in half to get it home.

Structural info: I have a 1947 house with 2 layers of about 1.5 inch thick total plank flooring as original subfloor, as measured from inside heat vent. Joists are about 14 inches apart. There are also diagonal wood plank supports along the joists, under the subfloor. My terms may be off here as I'm a total noob, but a pic from the basement is included in the photos linked up top.

Comment: 1.5 inches thick?  Are you sure?  Regardless, usually, if you have planks laid on top of diagonally laid subflooring, those planks will be finished hardwood flooring.  If they're 1.5 inches thick who knows what they are.  You should try sanding them down to see how they look.  Even if you want to tile this area you'll get a better idea what you have available in other rooms underneath any old carpets.   And if they're really 1.5 inches thick you could sand them down to a fantastic new finish, right through all the typical surface stains.

Comment: I don't think 1/4 inch plywood is suitable to bridge the step from vinyl to the parts of the floor where you have removed it.  By itself it will flex at the transition.  If you decide to keep the vinyl in place, get off cuts of similar thickness vinyl and glue them down where you have removed vinyl, to create an even surface below the plywood.  You don't have to fill small gaps between vinyl pieces.

Comment: There appear to be 2 pieces that are 1.5 inch thick total. Nothing about this house is standard or expected in my experience so far. Re: hardwood, I do already have nice hardwood throughout the house. This question is about tiling. As for flex, I am having a hard time understanding the role of the uncoupling membrane. Does it not help with some flex?

Comment: From my limited understanding (which is why I'm not writing an answer) you might consider cement board instead of plywood and membrane.   With cement board you may not need to repair the missing vinyl bits and you don't need membrane either.  Just Google "why use uncoupling membrane" to read about the situations where it really helps.

Comment: That was the original plan but I cannot work with heavy materials at the moment, hence the membrane